Changing file permissions from 777 to 755 or changing the owner doesn't do anything

[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ sudo chmod 755 luser-demo01.sh
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ ls -l
total 5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  101 May 30 19:44 luser-demo01.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 3464 May 30 19:16 Vagrantfile
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ chmod 755 luser-demo01.sh
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ ls -l
total 5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  101 May 30 19:44 luser-demo01.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 3464 May 30 19:16 Vagrantfile
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ 

I am trying to change file permissions for the above .sh file from 777 to 755 using chmod, but it's not working. I have tried using other permissions like 600 and 666 with chmod but the file permissions never change. I'm using CentOS 7.
My commands are the following: sudo chmod 755 <filename> or chmod 755 <filename>.
I was recommended to use chown to gain ownership of the file. However, after trying that, I see that even that is not working as expected. I am attaching an image below for reference. I am probably using the commands wrong.

[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ chown -c root luser-demo01.sh
changed ownership of 'luser-demo01.sh' from vagrant to root
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ ls -l
total 5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  101 May 30 19:44 luser-demo01.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 3464 May 30 19:16 Vagrantfile
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ 

The output of the findmnt command is as follows:
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ findmnt -T /vagrant
TARGET   SOURCE   FSTYPE OPTIONS
/vagrant /vagrant vboxsf rw,nodev,relatime
/vagrant vagrant  vboxsf rw,nodev,relatime


What is the filesystem? Is it local or something like NFS?

What is the filesystem the share is on?

The most common cause for this kind of behavior (note: no error messages when trying to change permissions or ownership) is that the files are located in a filesystem that does not support Unix-style file ownerships/permissions, like a VFAT/FAT32/ExFAT filesystem, or a SMB/CIFS share from a system that won't support the Unix extensions of the SMB protocol.
Such filesystems typically allow setting a default owner/group for all files and directories within, and perhaps one set of permissions for all files and another for all directories. These are usually set using mount options at filesystem mount time.
There are no error messages because the filesystem driver "knows" that changing the per-file ownerships and permissions is fundamentally not possible, so the driver simply does nothing and reports a successful operation whenever asked to change owners/permissions.
To identify the filesystem type used, run findmnt --target . in the directory that contains the files whose permissions you would like to change. Please edit your question to add the output of that command in it as text, not as a picture of text.

The filesystem type appears to be vboxsf, indicating this is a VirtualBox share from the host system. If VirtualBox is running as a regular user in the host system, it will have no privileges to change file ownerships on the host side. And if the host filesystem happens to be VFAT/FAT32/ExFAT, there will be no way to store the permissions for individual files, so the driver cannot rely on the host filesystem capabilities at all. So it will have to assume it must provide all the ownership/permissions emulation by itself, just like a VFAT filesystem driver has to do.
See man mount.vboxsf for mount options to use for setting the permissions.
